# iDangerous swipeNext and swipePrev don't animate

Tags: javascript, cordova, swiper.js

I have a swiper with a button for next and previous inside the slide content and when I click it it does not animate it just immediately displays the next slide. Swiping works fine. I am using it in a cordova app on ios. Here is an example of the slide html code.

```
<div id="slide2" class="swiper-slide" style=" background-image:url('img/backgrounds/jungle-home.png');
        background-position:50% 50%;
        background-size:cover; position:relative;">
        <!--************************
         ****************************
         Slide 2 - games 10-18
         ****************************
         *************************-->
        <div class="container-fluid" style=" display:; width:100%; height:100%; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; ">

            <div style="z-index: 0; width:100%; height:100%; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
                <div class="nav-arrow-left"><img src="img/ui/arrow-left.svg" ontouchstart="playTapSound(); prevPage();  return false;"></div>
                <div class="nav-arrow-right"><img src="img/ui/arrow-right.svg" ontouchstart="playTapSound(); nextPage();  return false;"></div>
```

and the javascript is

```
g_slider = new Swiper('.swiper-container',{
                              //Your options here:
                              mode:'horizontal'
                              //etc..
                              });
function prevPage() {
    g_slider.swipePrev();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is ontouchstart

if I change it to an onclick event it works fine.